# How to remove objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I achieve removing objects within an ArrayList. I tried the following code but the particles don't die. I outputted the size of the removeQue ArrayList and it outputs 1. The checkCollide method works fine for detecting collisions.

This is within a Class named Particles

```
  public void Update(){
    for(Enemies e: Enemies.enemies){
      if(this.checkCollide(e.x,e.y,e.mass)){
        removeQue.add(this);
      }
    }
    removeQue.clear(); // Remove objects
  }
```

More specifications:

Here is the whole class:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;

```
public class Particle{

  public static ArrayList<Particle> particles = new ArrayList<Particle>();
  public static ArrayList<Particle> removeQue = new ArrayList<Particle>();

  public static int particleCount;

  private int x,y,r,g,b,mass;

  private boolean playerParticle = false;

  private Color color = new Color((int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),(int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),(int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));

  public Particle(int x,int y, int mass, boolean p){
    particleCount++;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.mass = mass;
    playerParticle = p;
  }

  public void Update(){
    for(Enemies e: Enemies.enemies){
      if(this.checkCollide(e.x,e.y,e.mass) && !playerParticle){
        if(e.mass <= 200){
          e.addMass(this.mass);
        }
        if(e.mass >= 200){
          e.isTarget = false;
          e.goalReached = true;
          e.targetType = "c";
        }
        if(e.targetType.equals("p")){
          e.goalReached = true;
          e.isTarget = false;
        }
        this.x = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 10001);
        this.y = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 10001);
      }else if(this.checkCollide(e.x,e.y,e.mass) && playerParticle){
        e.addMass(this.mass);
        removeQue.add(this);
      }
    }
    removeQue.clear();
  }

  private boolean checkCollide(double x,double y,double mass){
    return x < this.x + 10 && x + mass > this.x && y < this.y + 10 && y + mass > this.y;
  }

  public void Draw(Graphics bbg){
    bbg.setColor(color);
    bbg.fillRect(x,y,10,10);
    bbg.drawRect(x,y,10,10);
  }


}
```

This is my main Update method

```
public void update(){
     for(Particle p: Particle.particles){
       p.Update();
     }

     for(Enemies e: Enemies.enemies){
       e.Update();
     }
   }
```

Comment: After your for loop you are calling clear(), how come it will output 1 for the size of removeQue?

Comment: I'm assuming it is because the contact between an enemy and a particle is continuous.

Comment: If you want remove a specific object, you can do `removeQue.remove( Object o )`, you can also remove using index if you know it by using `removeQue.remove( index )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're describing the situation correctly. After

```
removeQue.clear()
```

is called, the size of the ArrayList should be 0 since it is the last line of the method.

Comment: So what happens is that as soon as an enemy comes in contact with a particle it starts printing one but the particle remains there. Prior to contact It outputs nothing.

Comment: Where exactly is the ArrayList "removeQue" declared?

Comment: Within the Particle class. Would you like me to post my whole class?

Comment: Is your main problem that you're trying to resolve the fact that removeQue's size does not become 0 after the Update method is called? Sure, I'll take a look at the whole class.

Comment: My main problem is the fact that the particles are not getting removed. I posted the whole class file.

Comment: In your Update method, you use removeQue.clear(); to clear the particles? If you want to remove the particles, shouldn't you do particles.clear();? I'm not sure why you need the ArrayList removeQue from looking at your code.

Comment: The particles ArrayList holds all the particles that are active. As soon as the particle makes contact with the enemy it gets added to the removeQue ArrayList and from there I clear that array.

Comment: You don't have any code in the Update method that changes the particles ArrayList